# Unable to make Graph + iCloud works

Tags: graph, icloud, cosmicmind

what I have to write here?

```
db = Graph(cloud: "iCloud.com.devname.appname", completion: { (done, error) in
            if let errore = error {
                debugPrint("Error iCloud: \(errore.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
        })
```

or

```
db = Graph(cloud: "fantasyString", completion: { (done, error) in
            if let errore = error {
                debugPrint("Errore iCloud: \(errore.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
        })
```

I tried everything but I'm unable to make iCloud works

Thank you for your help, Daniel

EDIT:
the way I read data form db:

```
var customers : [Entity] {
        let search = Search<Entity>(graph: db).for(types: "Customers")
        return search.sync(completion: nil).sorted { ($0["name"] as! String) < ($1["name"] as! String)}
    }
```

the way I save the record:

```
func newCustomer(name:String, phone:String, mail:String, closure: @escaping ()->()) {

        let cliente = Entity(type: "Customers")
        cliente["name"] = name
        cliente["phone"] = phone
        cliente["mail"] = mail
        db.sync { (done, error) in
            if let errore = error {
                debugPrint("Errore addCustomer: \(errore.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            if done { closure() }
        }
    }
```

EDIT 2: the GraphDelegate implementation:

```
extension DataManager: GraphDelegate {

    func graphWillPrepareCloudStorage(graph: Graph, transition: GraphCloudStorageTransition) {
        debugPrint("graphWillPrepareCloudStorage")
        if transition == .initialImportCompleted {
            debugPrint("iCloud initialImportCompleted ok")
            self.clientiCont?.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    func graphDidPrepareCloudStorage(graph: Graph) {
        debugPrint("graphDidPrepareCloudStorage")
        self.clientiCont?.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func graphWillUpdateFromCloudStorage(graph: Graph) {
        debugPrint("graphWillUpdateFromCloudStorage")
        self.clientiCont?.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func graphDidUpdateFromCloudStorage(graph: Graph) {
        debugPrint("graphDidUpdateFromCloudStorage")
        // refresh clienti
        self.clientiCont?.tableView.reloadData()

        // refresh lista ordini
        self.gestCliCont?.tableOrder.reloadData()

        // refresh oridine
        self.gestOrdCont?.showOrder()
        self.gestOrdCont?.tableProdotti.reloadData()
    }


}
```

EDIT: the iCloud config
[image]

Comment: Hey, have you setup your iCloud container with Apple and enabled it in your app?

Comment: of course... what I have to write in the cloud string? The bundle identifier or a fantasy string?

Comment: I put the last part of the identifier. For example, if the identifier is `com.cosmicmind.Focus`, I put `Focus`. Also, make sure you have selected `iCloud Documents` in the Capabilities panel for iCloud.

Comment: no way, everything is set up correctly but no luck. Save and Search are the same?

Comment: Hmmm... this is a bit tricky to diagnose as I am not seeing the entire picture. Can you take a screenshot of your iCloud configuration, and show me your console log. Also, have you read this [article](http://www.cosmicmind.com/danieldahan/harness-apples-icloud-with-graph)?

Comment: the code is based on your article, and the iCloud config is the same as the screenshot I found on that article. There is something else to config?

Comment: Is it possible to share a sample project? There isn't enough code shown, and if your setup was like the article, all should be working. For example, I don't see in your code the usage of 

func graphDidPrepareCloudStorage(graph: Graph) {
        
}

Comment: Edited the question, added Delegate implementation, take a look

Comment: here you can download a sample App: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kyvglkjg8k1h71w/GraphCloudTest.zip?dl=0

Comment: cool, I will take a look :)

Comment: So I looked at your project and all ran successfully for me, after I put in my credentials, http://imgur.com/a/y9Th7. Check your container setup. Only allow document storage and use a container that shows all checkmarks once set.

Comment: have you tried to add and retrive a record? I'm unable to retrieve the records... the demo project works for you?

Comment: neither Watch and it''s delegate works with cloud....

Comment: Well it is not working with your current setup. So let's focus on discovering what is incorrect with your setup. How did you setup your storage container? Try adding a new one and describe what you did.

Comment: Ok, just edited the question with a screenshot form the Cloud config, by the way if you get my sample and try to make it work for yourself you'll see what I mean

Comment: everything looks correct, right?

Comment: I am using iCloud in my app that I am working on and all is fine. I will look at your edits and help you out :)

Comment: Hey Daniel, please make a NEW simple project and try for yourself if the iCloud feature works, I'm sure it doesn't...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to one of my students I found the bug:

- if you make a record this way everything works fine:
  `let record = Entity(type: "Names", graph: self.db)`
- but if you use this init it doesn't: `let record = Entity(type: "Names")`

so the solution is: make a record this way
`let record = Entity(type: "Names", graph: self.db)`